# Why this function gives 500 server error

Tags: php, codeigniter, internal-server-error

I have a company_add_product.php in the view folder and this is the code:

```
<?php
                    echo form_open_multipart('home/company_do_upload/', 'onsubmit="FormSubmit(this);"');
                    $disabled = array(
                            'class'       => 'form-control',
                            'maxlength'   => '100',
                            'style'       => 'width:100%',
                            );
                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                        echo '<label for="name"> ناو: </label>';
                        echo form_input('name', set_value('name'), $disabled);
                        echo '</div>';


                    $class = array(
                      'class'       => 'form-control',
                      'maxlength'   => '100',
                      'style'       => 'width:100%',
                    );
                        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                        echo '<label for="manufacturer"> ناوی کۆمپانیای بەرهەمهێن: </label>';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="manufacturer" />';
                        echo '<select name="manufacturer_ddl" class="form-control" onchange="DropDownChanged(this);">';
                        foreach ($manufacturers_name as $row) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['manufacturers_id'].'">'.$row['manufacturers_name'].'</option>';
                        }
                        echo '<option value="">تیای نییە..</option>';
                        echo '</select>';
                        echo '<input type="text" name="manufacturer_txt" style="display: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="تکایە ناوی کۆمپانیاکە بنوسە" />';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';


                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                        echo '<label for="model"> مۆدێل: </label>';
                        echo form_input('model', set_value('model'), $class);
                        echo '</div>';

                        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                        echo '<label for="category"> جۆری شمەک: </label>';
                        echo '<select name="category" class="form-control">';
                        foreach ($categories_name as $row) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['categories_id'].'">'.$row['categories_name'].'</option>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';


                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                        echo '<label for="price"> نرخی فرۆشتن: </label>';
                        echo form_input('price', set_value('price'), $class);
                        echo '</div>';

                        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
                        echo '<label for="stock"> دانە بۆ فرۆشتن: </label>';
                        echo form_input('stock', set_value('stock'), $class);
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';


                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<label for="used"> بەکارهاتووە: </label>';
                        echo form_checkbox('used', 'بەڵێ');
                        echo '</div>';


                        $textarea = array(
                        'class'  => 'form-control',
                        'rows'   => '5',
                        'cols'   => '10',
                        'style'  => 'width:48%',
                        'name'   => 'description',
                        );
                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<label for="description"> زانیاری زیاتر: </label>';
                        echo form_textarea($textarea, set_value('description'));
                        echo '</div>';



                        $img = array(
                          'class'       => 'form-control',
                          'maxlength'   => '100',
                          'style'       => 'width:25%',
                          'name'        => 'img',
                        );
                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<label for="img"> وێنەی سەرەکی: </label>';
                        echo form_upload('uploadedimages[0]','','multiple');
                        echo '</div>';

                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<label for="img"> وێنەی سەرەکی: </label>';
                        echo form_upload('uploadedimages[1]','','multiple');
                        echo '</div>';

                        echo '<div class="form-group">';
                        echo '<label for="img"> وێنەی سەرەکی: </label>';
                        echo form_upload('uploadedimages[2]','','multiple');
                        echo '</div>';


                        $submit_class  = array(
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                            );
                        echo '<input type="submit" value="upload" />';
                        echo form_close();
                        ?>
```

and this is the function in the controller that uploads the product:

```
function company_do_upload()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') || $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')){
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        //if save button was clicked, get the data sent via post
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {
            if (is_numeric($this->input->post('manufacturer'))) {
            //form validation
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'ناوی کاڵا', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('model', 'مۆدێل');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'جۆری کاڵا', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'نرخی کاڵا', 'required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('stock', 'دانە', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'ڕونکردنەوە');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');
                //if the form has passed through the validation
                if ($this->form_validation->run())
                {

                    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/products/temp';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = '1200';
                    $config['max_width']  = '720';
                    $config['max_height']  = '576';
                    $config['multi']  = 'ignore';

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimages'))
                    {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $data['featured_products']  = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 1);
                        $data['featured_offers']    = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 2);
                        $data['categories_name']    = $this->products_model->get_categories_name();
                        $error['main_content'] = 'pages/add_product';
                        $this->load->view('templates/template', $error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        if (!$data['upload_data'][1]['full_path']) {
                             $data['upload_data'][1]['full_path'] = NULL;
                        }

                        if (!$data['upload_data'][2]['full_path']) {
                             $data['upload_data'][2]['full_path'] = NULL;
                        }

                        $data_to_store = array(
                        'name'              => $this->input->post('name'),
                        'manufacturers_id'  => $this->input->post('manufacturer'),
                        'model'             => $this->input->post('model'),
                        'categories_id'     => $this->input->post('category'),
                        'sell_price'        => $this->input->post('price'),
                        'stock'             => $this->input->post('stock'),
                        'used'              => $this->input->post('used'),
                        'description'       => $this->input->post('description'),
                        'img'               => substr($config['upload_path'], 1).'/'.$data['upload_data'][0]['file_name'],
                        'img1'              => substr($config['upload_path'], 1).'/'.$data['upload_data'][1]['file_name'],
                        'img2'              => substr($config['upload_path'], 1).'/'.$data['upload_data'][2]['file_name'],
                        'product_date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'company_id'        => $this->session->userdata('company_id'),
                        'uploader_ip'       => $this->input->ip_address(),
                        );
                        //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
                        if($this->products_model->store_product($data_to_store) == TRUE){
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'کاڵاەکەت بەسەرکەوتویی بارکرا، سوپاس بۆ بەشداربونت.');

                            $data['featured_products']  = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 1);
                            $data['featured_offers']    = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 2);
                            $data['categories_name']    = $this->products_model->get_categories_name();
                            $data['main_content'] = 'pages/add_product';
                            $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
                        }else{
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'not_uploaded');
                        }
                    }

                }//validation run
                else{
                    $data['featured_products']  = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 1);
                    $data['featured_offers']    = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 2);
                    $data['categories_name']    = $this->products_model->get_categories_name();
                    $data['main_content'] = 'pages/add_product';
                    $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
                }

            }
            else{
                //form validation
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'ناوی کاڵا', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('manufacturer', 'ناوی کۆمپانیای بەرهەمهێن', 'is_unique[manufacturers.manufacturers_name]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('model', 'مۆدێل');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'جۆری کاڵا', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'نرخی کاڵا', 'required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('stock', 'ذانە', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'ڕونکردنەوە');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');
                //if the form has passed through the validation
                if ($this->form_validation->run())
                {

                    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/products/temp';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = '1200';
                    $config['max_width']  = '720';
                    $config['max_height']  = '576';
                    $config['multi']  = 'ignore';

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimages'))
                    {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $data['featured_products']  = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 1);
                        $data['featured_offers']    = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 2);
                        $data['categories_name']    = $this->products_model->get_categories_name();
                        $error['main_content'] = 'pages/add_product';
                        $this->load->view('templates/template', $error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $manufacturers_data = array('manufacturers_name' => $this->input->post('manufacturer'),);
                        $manufacturers_id = $this->manufacturers_model->store_manufacture($manufacturers_data);
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                        if (!$data['upload_data'][1]['full_path']) {
                             $data['upload_data'][1]['full_path'] = NULL;
                        }

                        if (!$data['upload_data'][2]['full_path']) {
                             $data['upload_data'][2]['full_path'] = NULL;
                        }

                        $data_to_store = array(
                        'name'              => $this->input->post('name'),
                        'manufacturers_id'  => $manufacturers_id,
                        'model'             => $this->input->post('model'),
                        'categories_id'     => $this->input->post('category'),
                        'sell_price'        => $this->input->post('price'),
                        'stock'             => $this->input->post('stock'),
                        'used'              => $this->input->post('used'),
                        'description'       => $this->input->post('description'),
                        'img'               => substr($config['upload_path'], 1).'/'.$data['upload_data'][0]['file_name'],
                        'img1'              => substr($config['upload_path'], 1).'/'.$data['upload_data'][1]['file_name'],
                        'img2'              => substr($config['upload_path'], 1).'/'.$data['upload_data'][2]['file_name'],
                        'product_date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'company_id'         => $this->session->userdata('company_id'),
                        'uploader_ip'       => $this->input->ip_address(),
                        );
                        //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
                        if($this->products_model->store_product($data_to_store) == TRUE){
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'کاڵاەکەت بەسەرکەوتویی بارکرا، سوپاس بۆ بەشداربونت.');

                            $data['featured_products']  = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 1);
                            $data['featured_offers']    = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 2);
                            $data['categories_name']    = $this->products_model->get_categories_name();
                            $data['main_content'] = 'pages/add_product';
                            $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
                        }else{
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'not_uploaded');
                        }
                    }

                }//validation run
                else{
                    $data['featured_products']  = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 1);
                    $data['featured_offers']    = $this->products_model->get_featured_products(4, 2);
                    $data['categories_name']    = $this->products_model->get_categories_name();
                    $data['main_content'] = 'pages/add_product';
                    $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
                }
            }
        }

        else{
                redirect('home/company_add_product'); 
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the model:

```
function store_product($data)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert('products', $data);
        return $insert;
    }
```

but the problem is when I upload a product lets say when the

> company_do_upload()

fires, the entire website goes down and gives 500 internal error.
my website is on dreamhost, and I uploaded the files after the crash to godaddy it's the same, gives 500 internal error. but when I upload my entire website that I have backup before the crash it's working again. I dont know it looks like this code breaks some files. I did contact the support team twice they say its the error is not on their side.

Comment: check your error_log file of your web server, you can find it on your ftp.

Comment: I will just add the error log too. thanks

Comment: Add only the part that is pertinent to your issue not the whole file. [Here you can see how to look at it on dreamhost.](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Error_log)

Comment: Actually I have to read about this **var_dump(__FILE__.LINE_);** to know what you are talking about, but as I said above when I fire upload button and goes to the next function **company_do_upload()** it gives 500 internal error and then the entire website gives 500 error.

Comment: You have to post the information referent to the script youre running from your error_log file otherwise it will hold no meaning.

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent the application is in production mode if you mean that

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent you are right I need to learn debugging and I appreciate it realy that you are trying with me thanks

Answer (score 0):

The log snippet you have shows an error being triggered not by your code necessarily, but rather by a configuration file.  What's at `line 195` in `/dh/apache2/template/etc/mod_sec2/99_dreamhost_rules.conf` ?  I would imagine if something in your code were actually triggering the 500 error, there'd be something in the log referencing your PHP file.  Your snippet of the log doesn't show that this is the case.

If it IS your code, put calls to a logging function in different places and see where it gets.  This is what I've done when the httpd logs didn't help me.  Here's the logging function I used:

```
function logit($msg){
try {
    $fh=fopen('/tmp/file.log','a');
    fwrite($fh,date("Ymd His")."\t$msg\n");
    fclose($fh);
} catch (Exception $ex){
    // Forget it!
} // try..catch
} // logit
```

It automatically adds a timestamp to the message sent to the file. The function purposely closes the log file after each call to force a buffer flush to ensure if your program dies the log will be as up to date as possible.  This has helped me out of a lot of tight scrapes.  I place a call to the log at the beginning and end of the routine causing problems:

```
function foo(){
    logit("Foo():start");
    // do something
    logit("Starting potential trouble: some potentially troublesome value='$bar'");
    // The single quotes around $bar help if $bar is not assigned a value
    // problem code
    logit("Foo():done");
} //foo
```

Just be absolutely sure the directory and file in the `fopen()` call is writable by the web server process!  Having said that, is the path where you have PHP placing uploaded files in `company_do_upload()` writable by the web server?